# Problema ao alinhar Rodapé

Tags: html, css, css3

Olá, eu tenho um problema que está perturbando a muito tempo, eu tenho uma pagina na qual há uma `div` cuja tem vários conteúdos dentro que se modificam de acordo com o desejo do usuário, logo abaixo existe um Rodapé.

Caso eu coloque um `position: relative`, o rodapé irá adequar sua posição de acordo com o tamanho da página, porém ele não fica "preso" em baixo (sem nenhum espaço até o fim dá page) caso o altura do monitor se altere. Já caso eu coloque um `position: absolute` o footer irá ficar fixo no fim da página, mas não se adequará ao tamanho da janela. Então não sei como fazer para "mesclar" as duas configurações necessárias.

Meu exemplo está [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/SamirChaves/c2jpt2j2/2/).

Obrigado.

Comment: Vc quer que ele fique preso quando o usuário desce a barra de rolagem?

Comment: Ja tentou colocar `position: fixed`?

Comment: Se o que entendi, só usar position:fixed; bottom:0

Comment: Talvez eu não tenha me expressado bem, eu não desejo que o rodapé esteja com um `position: fixed`, e sim com um `position: relative` ou com um `position: absolute`, o problema está em suas características primitivas, no caso do `position: relative` ele irá mudar sua posição (sua localização, não sua posição `css`) de acordo com o tamanho dos elementos que se localizam antes dele, porém não encontro um jeito de colocar um `bottom: 0px` semelhante ao que acontece caso eu aplique um `position: absolute`. Alguém sabe como seria possível fazer isso?

Comment: Eu juro que tentei entender mas ainda não consegui claramente. Você quer sua div de rodapé em bottom: 0px quando o conteúdo não é grande suficiente para estourar a página, e deixar sempre abaixo da div "page" quando o conteúdo dessa div estourar o tamanho da página? Seria como a classe "footer" do bootstrap 3? Já viu o [exemplo do bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/)?

Comment: @AdrianoLeal, pelo que vi acho que você entendeu, porém ainda não consegui resolver.

Comment: @SamirBraga não consegui continuar meus testes mas assim que conseguir posto aqui. Veja que também nunca fiz isso, hahaha, mas entendendo sua ideia vou tentar ajudar. =)

Answer (score 1):

Bom, não sei se é a melhor alternativa, mas a solução que encontrei foi essa:

```
<body>
  <style>
  * {
    margin: 0;
  }
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
  }
  .page {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -4em;
  }
  .rodape, .push {
    height: 4em;
  }

  .rodape { 
      background: #3C948B;
  }
  </style>

  <div class="page">
      <p>Your website content here.</p></br>
      <p>Your website content here.</p></br>
      <p>Your website content here.</p></br>
      <p>Your website content here.</p></br>
      <p>Your website content here.</p></br>
      <p>Your website content here.</p></br>
      <p>Your website content here.</p></br>
      <p>Your website content here.</p></br>
      <p>Your website content here.</p></br>
      <p>Your website content here.</p></br>

      <div class="push"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="rodape">
        <p style="vertical-align: middle; position: relative; top: 28px; margin-left: 20px;
         color: rgb(255, 255, 255)" >TechSmart&copy; WebResolution&reg; - 2014</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Veja que a função da `<div class="push">` é apenas empurrar seu **rodapé** quando o conteúdo não é grande o suficiente para ter scroll na página.

A partir dessa exemplo você pode ir adaptando conforme suas necessidades.

Se alguém quiser conferir a fonte da resposta, segue o [link](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/).